# Proper use of grunt lib from within an Assemble plugin

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, assemble

I'm working on an Assemble (v0.4.x) plugin and need to use the Grunt API for some tasks. I noticed that Assemble includes Grunt in the params passed to the plugin. Is there any particular reason I should use this Grunt instead of requiring it myself?

I'm asking because I'm building fixtures for testing the plugin as well. If I don't require Grunt in the module, then I'll have to add grunt to the fixture before running the test.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `grunt` passed by Assemble, it ensures that you're always using the same instance of Grunt. This should be easier in v0.5 since Assemble won't depend on Grunt.